# How do I scrape website HTML after Javascript has run?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

So I was trying to scrape a website. When I scrape it, it turns out that the result isn't the same as when you try to right click and view page source on Mozilla or Google Chrome.

The code I used:

```
import urllib

page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/search?q=python") 
#or any other website that uses search
python = page.read()
print python
```

It turns out that the code only takes the 'raw' web page, which isn't what I wanted. For websites like this, I want the code after javascript etc. has run. So that the result is the same as if you were right clicking and viewing source code from your browser.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Either look at browser automation using something like Selenium or "headless browsing"

Answer (score 1):

its not exactly a raw page as it is an error page from google to you : 
in the `print python` part it says on the top of the message :

> Your client does not have permission to get URL `/search?q=python` from this server.

if you were to change your `page` variable to

```
page = urllib.urlopen("http://volt.al/")
```

you'd see the javascript.

try it out with different pages to see what you like